# How do I format a double to currency rounded to the nearest dollar?

Tags: c#, formatting, rounding, currency

Right now I have

```
double numba = 5212.6312
String.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToInt32(numba) )
```

This will give me

```
$5,213.00
```

but I don't want the ".00".

I know I can just drop the last three characters of the string every time to achieve the effect, but seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: numba is a bad name for a variable... One more character would have given you "number"

Comment: Omar is correct, however "number" is also a crap name for a variable.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

First - don't keep currency in a `double` - use a `decimal` instead. Every time. Then use "C0" as the format specifier:

```
decimal numba = 5212.6312M;
string s = numba.ToString("C0");
```

Comment: No floating point should really be used as a currency field. An integer storing in cents/pence/lowest allowable currency unit is the only way to avoid rounding errors (and a BigInt library if you need numbers beyond a long ints range :))

Comment: An integer has similar rounding issues as decimal... decimal is essentially a largish integer with a precision specifier. Most things you can do with int you can do with decimal, plus decimal is 96-bits (rather that 32 or 64 for int and long). Most currencies fit into 96 bits...

Comment: I'll second the prohibition on using doubles for currency. The imprecision can lead to trouble and, if bad enough, audits.

Comment: I would just add that the prohibition on using floating-points for amounts of money is not always relevant.  For example, with non-precise future projections, doubles are fine.

Comment: Don't really agree here. Most investment banks store their values doubles. As long as you know what you are doing and know about cancellations and precision issues it should be fine.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the performance of doubles is also much better than decimals in .NET

Comment: @geedubb while that is *true*, it usually doesn't really matter how fast you get to the wrong answer ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell haha very true ;)

Comment: new simplfied syntax is:
string s = numba:C0

Answer (score 25):

This should do the job:

```
String.Format("{0:C0}", Convert.ToInt32(numba))
```

The number after the `C` specifies the number of decimal places to include.

I suspect you really want to be using the [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.80).aspx) type for storing such numbers however.

Answer (score 5):

```
Console.WriteLine(numba.ToString("C0"));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 decimal value = 0.00M;
        value = Convert.ToDecimal(12345.12345);
        Console.WriteLine(".ToString(\"C\") Formates With Currency $ Sign");
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C"));
        //OutPut : $12345.12
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C1"));
        //OutPut : $12345.1
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C2"));
        //OutPut : $12345.12
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3"));
        //OutPut : $12345.123
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C4"));
        //OutPut : $12345.1235
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C5"));
        //OutPut : $12345.12345
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C6"));
        //OutPut : $12345.123450
```

[click to see Console Out Put screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N0sz.png)

Hope this may Help you...

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the right way to achieve your goal is with this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
```

and only then you should do the Format call:

```
String.Format("{0:C0}", numba)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple: `numba.ToString("C2")`

more @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString