# String Formatting with currency double values not displaying correctly.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC3 with a detailed view that needs to display a formatted dollar amounts like $1,200.00. The controller is passing in a double value in this case for MonthlyMortgage to the view. The line of code below however, does not display the correct string formatting. What is displayed is $1200.00, and what I need is $1,200.00.

I have tried:

```
$@String.Format("{0:c}", Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MonthlyMortgage))
```

and I have tried this:

```
$@String.Format("{0:#,###,###,##0.000}", Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MonthlyMortgage))
```

Can someone please enplane why this is not working?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890100/how-do-i-format-a-double-to-currency-rounded-to-the-nearst-dollar

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to use `Html.DisplayFor` because it will return `MvcHtmlString` so the `string.Format` doesn't apply.

Just use the `string.Format` on your model:

```
@String.Format("{0:c}", Model.MonthlyMortgage)
```

Note you don't need the '$' sign anymore because the `{0:c}` will take care of it.

Comment: That was nice. I never thought of using the Model property directly which corrected my problem. Thanks...

Answer (score 11):

@nemesv has a direct answer. The other option would be to remove  `String.Format()` from the View and use DataAnnotations to attach a formatting to MonthlyMortgage.

An example from MSDN:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public Decimal ListPrice { get; set; }
```

And btw, `#,###,###,##0.000` can be shortened to `#,##0.00`

Comment: IMO, the best answer since I was needing to have mine in `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CurrencyProperty)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the `[DataType]` attribute.

Add DataAnnotations `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` and `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` then you can do something like this in the model.

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
public decimal MonthlyMortgage{ get; set; }
```