# DataAnnotation for float not working

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations

In one of our `ASP.NET Core 1.1` project, I'm getting the following error when rendering following `View`. I think I'm correctly following suggestions from `SO` users like `@DarinDimitrov` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9465405/1232087)

**Error**: `Input string was not in correct format`

**ViewModel**:

```
Public Class OrdersViewModel
{
    ....
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{(0:C)}")]
    public float? price { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MyProj.Models.OrdersViewModel
@{
Layout = "";
}
....
<tr>
    <td>Price:</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(t => t.price)</td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE**:

This `@String.Format("{0:c}", Model.price)` works as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175948/1232087) by `@nemesv`. But I don't want to use it in the view since ModelView is used at multiple places on various views. So I would like to keep using `DisplayFor(...)` at those places instead - as it's a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

`System.FormatException` that you have means that your `DataFormatString` is wrong. In your case you need to remove `()` from format string (explicit call of `String.Format` works as uses the different template):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public float? price { get; set; }
```

If you need the result string to be like `(123.45)`, not `123.45` then do

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "({0:C})")]
```