# Remove decimals in a currency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format a double to currency rounded to the nearst dollar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890100/how-do-i-format-a-double-to-currency-rounded-to-the-nearst-dollar)

How can i remove decimal from a currency?

Here is how I format a number to currency:

```
string.Format("{0:C}", Amount)
```

The output is $20,000,000.00 but I need $20,000,000

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this answers your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890100/how-do-i-format-a-double-to-currency-rounded-to-the-nearst-dollar

Comment: Amount.Trim('0').Trim('.') ;

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Specify you want zero decimal places:

```
String.Format("{0:C0}",Amount)
```