# Syntax to extract DataGridViewCell value without conversion

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I know I can do this:

```
Dim Amount As Double = CDbl(DGVRow.Cells("Amount").Value)
```

But my DGV cell is already a `Double` so I would get his value without conversion.

I've tried the below code (but it isn't the right syntax)

```
Dim Amount As Double = DGVRow.Cells.OfType(Of Double)("Amount").Value
```

Comment: Since a column/cell needs to be able contain anything, it returns `Object` which means your value is boxed.  If you have a datasource, you *can* do much what you are asking:  `Dim d = dt.Rows(n).Field(Of Double)("Amount")`.  There is still a conversion, just a different kind.  Decimal would be a better choice for money type values though

Comment: @Plutonix No. In this case I have no datatable set as source. I chose 'Double' because I have to do calculation which use 'Double' and I don't need extreme precision. Anyway thanks for your precious hints ;)

Comment: *Especially* if it is money *and* there are calculations, `Decimal` is a better choice.  It prevents rounding errors - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1165761 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/890100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that it will always contain a Double, you should use `DirectCast`

```
Dim Amount As Double = DirectCast(DGVRow.Cells("Amount").Value, Double)
```

These all produce resulting variables of type Double

```
Dim value As Object
value = 1.23#
Dim resultDC = DirectCast(value, Double)
Dim resultCT = CType(value, Double)
Dim resultCDBL = CDbl(value)
```

But there are different things going on behind the scenes. DirectCast is the most straightforward.

Check this post [Difference between DirectCast() and CType() in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056514/difference-between-directcast-and-ctype-in-vb-net) which details the difference between the conversion methods in VB.net. Also this one [VB CStr, CDate, CBool, etc. vs. DirectCast for casting without conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379537/vb-cstr-cdate-cbool-etc-vs-directcast-for-casting-without-conversion).

Basically, DirectCast is preferred when you know your Object contains the type you expect, so no conversion is necessary. It will be faster than the other options.

Answer (score 1):

If you sure that cell contains value of type `Double` then use `DirectCast`

```
Dim Amount As Double = DirectCast(DGVRow.Cells("Amount").Value, Double)
```

Other way will be working straight with values of bounded DataSource, as @Plutonix explained in the comments